# How to install linux usbserial kernel driver manually?

Tags: kernel-module, usbserial

I have a ubuntu 16.04 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-148-generic host machine. I don't have serial dictionary in

`/lib/modules/4.4.0-148-generic/kernel/drivers/usb`

So i need to install it manually, but i can't find the source code and build document.

Thanks for your time and hope you can help me out! :)

Comment: That module is in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem taht /dev/ttyUSB0 is not found  after I upgrade the kernel source.

You can use the below command to install USBSerial driver and then /dev/ttyUSB0 will come up again.

```
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Hope to fix your problem.

Comment: I remembered I solve it by specific compiler the USBSerial driver and add it, also update initramfs https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405146/removed-lib-modules-folder-after-every-reboot  to make it persistence.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems this module is in the kernel source :)